# Why getting "Segmentation fault" for the dynamically allocated 2-D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to generate pascal triangle by using the 2-d array which is dynamically allocated. But when I tried to run, its giving me "Segmentation Fault" error. What I am doing wrong in the code ?

```
int ** generate(int A, int *number_of_rows) {

     *number_of_rows = A;
     int **result = (int **)malloc(A * sizeof(int *));
     int i,j;
     for(i=0; i < A; i++){
         for(j=0; j<= i; j++){
             if(i==j || j==0)
                result[i][j] = 1;
             else
                result[i][j] = result[i-1][j] + result[i-1][j-1];
         }
     }
     return result;


}
```

Someone say I need to allocate memory for each row like below

```
for (i = 0; i < A; i++) 
        result[i] = (int *)malloc(i * sizeof(int));
```

but after doing that the function returns 
`[0 ] [1 ] [2 ] [3 ] [4 ]` 
instead of 
`[1 ] [1 1 ] [1 2 1 ] [1 3 3 1 ] [1 4 6 4 1 ]` for A = 5

Comment: Standard warning: [Do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1151654)

Comment: @Eregrith I did but same result.

Comment: I know, i did not say it was your problem, it's simply a standard warning against something you should not do.

Comment: What "someone said" was correct but as you go `for( j=0; j<=i; j++ )` it must be `result[i] = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Tried. Now I am getting [0 ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]

Comment: @kikit Give the main function as well .

Comment: @Kikit it work for me, [DEMO](http://ideone.com/k8YqLO)

Answer (score 1):

You've allocated memory for the array of rows, but you haven't allocated memory for each row.

Currently `result[i]` points to unallocated memory.